# Get transaction by invoiceId in paypal api

Tags: paypal

I'm looking for the correct endpoint to use in the Paypal API for looking up a transaction by invoice id. We submit the invoice id to paypal when redirecting customers to PayPal for payment on their site. In order for us to resolve abandoned carts correctly, I need to look these invoice ids back up in paypal to see if there are completed transactions or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TransactionSearch API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/), and use the INVNUM as the criteria to search by.  The [API Endpoint](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/) will depend on if you are trying this on live or sandbox, what type of format you are using, and what type of authentication you are using.  You can find a list of the endpoints [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/).